# Specify the name of the object that will be used for implicit mapping by MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I would like to know if it's possible in MapStruct to specify explicitly what is the object that will be used for implicit mapping among the ones passed in argument to the mapper, I have the following example :

```
@Mapping(target = "ca1", source = "a.ca1")
@Mapping(target = "ca2", source = "a.ca2")
C mapFrom(A a, B b);
```

I want to use A for explicit mapping and B for all implicit mapping, the issue is that A and B have a lot of properties with same name that conflicts together, I tried to use

```
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "b")
```

but that does not solve the issue, I still get java: Several possible source properties for target property... Error, also using the `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)` will make it very difficult as I will have to wirte by hand a lot of mappings. I think it will be very handy if we could specify the object that will be used for implicit mapping, any help ? (I am using version 1.5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters):

> In case several source objects define a property with the same name,
> the source parameter from which to retrieve the property must be
> specified using the @Mapping annotation as shown for the description
> property in the example. An error will be raised when such an
> ambiguity is not resolved.

However, needed functionality could be achieved with a next workaround of 3 methods:

```
@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {

    TestMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TestMapper.class);

    default ResultClass combineOrdered(ImplicitClass implicitClass, ExplicitClass explicitClass) {
        ResultClass resultClass = populateImplicitly(implicitClass);
        populateExplicitly(resultClass, explicitClass);
        return resultClass;
    }

    ResultClass populateImplicitly(ImplicitClass implicitClass);

    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
    @Mapping(source = "explicitClass.explicitField", target = "explicitField")
    void populateExplicitly(@MappingTarget ResultClass resultClass, ExplicitClass explicitClass);
}
```

MapStruct will generate code for `populateImplicitly` method to implicitly populate all fields from ImplicitClass - and code for `populateExplicitly` method to explicitly populate only declared fields from ExplicitClass.

And those 2 approaches could be combined using additional method `combineOrdered` - which will first call implicit mappings (to populate all the fields) - and then will populate only explicit fields.

Usage of such `combineOrdered` method should help to do what you're looking for.